# OpenCV cv2.VideoCapture(0) is not working well with webcam

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am trying to use a USB webcam for a computer vision project on a `raspberry pi` that outputs the diminations of moving object. I installed `openCV` and tried my `python` code which it worked perfect on my PC, but when I ran it in my `raspberry pi B+` and the output was unexpected so I took a video output with `cv2.imshow("video output", frame)` to see whats going on and saw some thing strange. the video was flickering with some part red and some part blue.

---

[image: view the porblem]

although my code worked perfect in pc but maybe it can help, so here is my code:

```
import argparse
import datetime
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", help="path to video")
ap.add_argument("-a", "--min-area", type=int, default = 200, help="min area")
args=vars(ap.parse_args())

if args.get("video", None) is None:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    camera.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,2)
    camera.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640)
    camera.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480)
    time.sleep(2.5)
else:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

while True:
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
    if not grabbed:
        break
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    cv2.imshow("testing",frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: @kasra I don't think it has something to do with code. But I will add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was from the video source. The webcam was not compatible with OpenCV Although it worked with some other computer video input package very well